# Sort List but can't compare directly two models

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I have `MyModel` class with `childNames` field contains some references to it

```
class MyModel{
    private String name;
    private List<String> childNames = new ArrayList<>();
    public MyModel(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public List<String> getChildNames() {
        return childNames;
    }
    public void setChildNames(List<String> childNames) {
        this.childNames = childNames;
    }
}
```

I have a list MyModel and want to sort with rule :

```
MyModel a = new MyModel("a");
a.setChildNames(Arrays.asList("b", "b1" ,"b2"));  --> mean a > b, a > b1...
MyModel b = new MyModel("b");
b.setChildNames(Arrays.asList("d", "d1" ));  --> mean b > d, b > d1
MyModel c = new MyModel("c");
c.setChildNames(Arrays.asList("d", "d2"));  --> mean c > d, c > d2
MyModel d = new MyModel("d");
d.setChildNames(Arrays.asList("e"));  --> mean d > e
MyModel e = new MyModel("e");
List<MyModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(a);
list.add(b);
list.add(c);
list.add(d);
list.add(e);
```

So I expect result when sorting list is : `e,d,c,b,a` or `e,d,b,c,a`

This is my try with comparator but not work, because can't compare directly between two model (example compare `a` and `d`)

```
Comparator<MyModel> comparator = (m1, m2) -> {
    if (m1.getChildNames().contains(m2.getName())){
        return 1;
    }
    if (m2.getChildNames().contains(m1.getName())){
        return -1;
    }
    return 0; 
};
list.sort(comparator);
```

Any suggestion in this case?

Comment: You are doing it wrong. You'll have to re-think the comparator logic as it will return `0` and not `1` when `e` and `a` are being compared.

Comment: Yes it's wrong that why i need some help here for better suggestion in code or algorithm

Comment: Rather than storing `private List<String> childNames = new ArrayList<>();` in each `MyModel`, it would be better to store `private List<MyModel> children= new ArrayList<>();`

Then you can check if a child of a `MyModel` has a child also

Answer (score 2):

First of all your Model structure is a problem, you shall have childs also as a List of MyModel. That way it will be easier to maintain hierarchy and traverse it.

Your current logic miss the condition where m1 and m2 are not in immediate hierarchy. So you should traverse this hierarchy something like this:

```
Comparator<MyModel> comparator = new Comparator<MyModel>() {
         public int compare(MyModel m1, MyModel m2) {
            if (m1.getChildNames().contains(m2.getName())){
                return 1;
            }
            if (m2.getChildNames().contains(m1.getName())){
                return -1;
            }

            while(!m1.getChildNames().isEmpty()) {
                for (String child : m1.getChildNames()) {
                    for (MyModel myModel : list) {
                        if(myModel.name.equals(child)) {
                            return compare(myModel, m2);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return 0; 
        }};
```

If you have kept child also as MyModel's list than use of **list** could have been avoided. Currently it is required to find out the child object.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
Comparator<MyModel> comparator = (m1, m2) -> {
            if (m1.getChildNames().contains(m2.getName())){
                return 1;
            }
            return -1;
        };
```

Comment: it's failed in case : m1.getChildNames() is empty and m2.getChildNames() contains m1

Answer (score 0):

Change your model to this:

```
class MyModel{
    private String name;
    private List<MyModel> children = new ArrayList<>();
    public MyModel(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public List<MyModel> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }
    public void setChildren(List<MyModel> children) {
        this.children= children;
    }
    public void addChild(MyModel child){
        this.children.add(child);
    }
}
```

This way you can check each child if they have a child and do the comparison that way. It's a lot easier than having just strings, use your objects wisely. I'll let you do the comparator yourself. I would suggest making a recursive method to check the comparison, or you might be there for some time writing the code!

Comment: I just minimized the code in project to ask, childNames is a weak reference and i need use it to build a real reference

Comment: Then you'll need to use Sanjeev's code posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36789082/833070).

That should sort your issue out. I wasn't aware you couldn't create a direct reference in the class